# Directory API User Insert doesn't have salt parameter for password hash

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm looking at this method:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert

It takes *password* and *hashFunction* as parameters. I was expecting to also have the ability to provide the *salt* that was used for hashing the password. If Google does not support this, then I don't think this is a very secure way to handle password hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Google could hash the hash you send, that time with a salt. Since the salt is just a random value it doesn't make much sense to send it.

Comment: And how would this be enough?

Comment: Let's imagine (I don't really know!) how Google web auth works.
Google hashes the password with no salt, then rehashes (with salt) the password and checks if it matches their DB.
That first hash could be the provided one, yet it was never saved on DB. Thus, super-secure.
Of course another possibility would be that the provided hash is saved on their DB and that's all.

Comment: I'm sure google stores a salted hash of the password, but what is the point of hashing the password in the api call? If the call is intercepted in some way then an unsalted hash is vulnerable to attack in a way that a salted hash is not. I suppose it's somewhat better than sending the password plain text, but not by very much because it is easy to look up unsalted hashes of vast numbers of (common) passwords.